# Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar to varbinary is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query

Tags: asp.net

I have following code for button click.
status is bit
registerName is nvarchar
I dont know what the problem is.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(MiniMartSystem.dbConnection.dbConn_local);//(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnectionString1"].ConnectionString);
SqlCommand register = new SqlCommand("Insert Into Register (firstName,lastName,userName,Password,emailAddress,mobileNo,Department,dateofRegister,Status,registerName) VALUES (@firstName,@lastName,@userName,@Password,@emailAddress,@mobileNo,@Department,@dateofRegister,@Status,@registerName)", conn);

register.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
register.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", tb_firstname.Text);
register.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", tb_lastname.Text);
register.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", tb_loginname.Text);
register.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", tb_passowrd.Text);
register.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emailAddress", tb_emailaddress.Text);
register.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobileNo", tb_mobiletno.Text);
register.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Department", dd_department.Text);
register.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateofRegister", DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
register.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", "True");
register.Parameters.AddWithValue("@registerName", MiniMartSystem.dbConnection.username);

conn.Open();
```

Comment: You must check the table declaration, are you sure you don't have any columns in there that is of type varbinary? **And more serious, are you really storing passwords in cleartext?**

Comment: If `dateofRegister` is a `datetime` don't convert it to string. If `Status` is a `bit` don't convert it to string. In short: don't use the wrong type.